# angular 2 child component managment

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a parent component that contains a table, and a child component that contains a bootstrap modal.

When a row in the table is clicked the modal should pop up with many functions and filtered select-drop-boxes that matches the clicked row.

From my understanding, these three are my options:

**A.** Opening the modal with a function inside the child component (the modal) via `@Viewchild`. When closed, another function in the child component should clear the properties and fields in the modal.

pros: The DOM will not have to recreate the child component each time a row is clicked.

cons: If the modal is not needed it will be created unnecessarily. + I have to reset the fields on close.

---

**B.** Use `*ngIf` on the child component (the modal). When a row is clicked, the `if` statement becomes `true` and in the `ngOnInit` the modal will call a method to pop up the modal.

pros: No need to reset the fields, everything will be set in the `ngOnInit`.

cons: will be created each time a row is clicked.

---

**C.** use a message service between the parent and the child that will trigger show/hide on the modal.

cons: a service needs to be built for this.

---

I would like to understand what is considered a good practice and what's a bad practice in these approaches. Or alternative ways to achieve this. I'm working on a big project and need to do this a lot.

Comment: Bootstrap modals aren't really made for Angular. I would suggest that you use subjects to control your modal (init and reset), which will be easy to achieve, and to display it, you should reference the child as a view child and call its methods.

Comment: similar to A case? or did I missed something from your comment?

Comment: The use of subjects to control your modal status, but yes, similar to A

Comment: can you direct me to an example? I'm not sure I understand the "use of subjects" term...

Comment: RxJS `Subject`s to proagate events, similar to `BehaviorSubject`s ?

Comment: oh I didn't know about the `subjects ` and `BehaviorSubjects`, after some reading I understands that this is what I did in my **C** case.

Comment: (Again, that's my personal opinion, not the best practice, so keep that in mind)